# IllegalStateException: SQLite cursor already closed

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

Below I am posting the logcat details. Please tell me How to resolve that.

```
11-21 14:49:33.604: E/AndroidRuntime(1721): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-21 14:49:33.604: E/AndroidRuntime(1721): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.shaktitool/com.example.shaktitool.Product}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: trying to requery an already closed cursor  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@41334490
11-21 14:49:33.604: E/AndroidRuntime(1721):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2575)
11-21 14:49:33.604: E/AndroidRuntime(1721):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2603)
11-21 14:49:33.604: E/AndroidRuntime(1721):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
11-21 14:49:33.604: E/AndroidRuntime(1721):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-21 14:49:33.604: E/AndroidRuntime(1721):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-21 14:49:33.604: E/AndroidRuntime(1721):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-21 14:49:33.604: E/AndroidRuntime(1721):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-21 14:49:33.604: E/AndroidRuntime(1721):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-21 14:49:33.604: E/AndroidRuntime(1721):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-21 14:49:33.604: E/AndroidRuntime(1721):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-21 14:49:33.604: E/AndroidRuntime(1721):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-21 14:49:33.604: E/AndroidRuntime(1721): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: trying to requery an already closed cursor  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@41334490
11-21 14:49:33.604: E/AndroidRuntime(1721):     at android.app.Activity.performRestart(Activity.java:5051)
11-21 14:49:33.604: E/AndroidRuntime(1721):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5074)
11-21 14:49:33.604: E/AndroidRuntime(1721):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2565)
11-21 14:49:33.604: E/AndroidRuntime(1721):     ... 10 more
```

My Java Code:

```
package com.example.shaktitool;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.KeyEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;



    public class Product extends Activity {

    protected static final String PRODUCT_REQUEST = null;

    private SQLiteAdapterPro mySQLiteAdapter;

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.product);

            Intent intent = getIntent();

            ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.content_list);


            /*
             *  Create/Open a SQLite database
             *  and fill with dummy content
             *  and close it
             */
            mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapterPro(this);
            mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();
            mySQLiteAdapter.deleteAll();

            mySQLiteAdapter.insert("ELECTRONICS-COMPUTERS");
            mySQLiteAdapter.insert("DESKTOPS");
            mySQLiteAdapter.insert("NOTEBOOKS");

            mySQLiteAdapter.close();

            /*
             *  Open the same SQLite database
             *  and read all it's content.
             */
            mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapterPro(this);
            mySQLiteAdapter.openToRead();

            Cursor cursor = mySQLiteAdapter.queueAll();
            startManagingCursor(cursor);

            String[] from = new String[]{SQLiteAdapter.KEY_CONTENT};
            int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text};

            SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter =
                new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, cursor, from, to);

            list.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);

            list.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener() {

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int position, long arg3) {

                    switch(position){

                    case 1 : Intent intent = new Intent(Product.this, Desktop.class);
                             startActivity(intent);

                             break;

                    case 2 : Intent intent1 = new Intent(Product.this, Notebook.class);
                             startActivity(intent1);

                             break;                        


                    }
                }   
            });


            mySQLiteAdapter.close();



        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem is that when I press Back button the application is closed. What should I do that when I press Back button I have to go to previous activity.

Comment: this is very common please check your code Cursor is closed or new cursor provided to this adapter so this exception is coming , You may avoid calling this             mySQLiteAdapter.close();
 (Not sure about adapter code) ,  Second thing you can post the Adapter code then i can tell the root cause..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**First:** your should read the FAQ of StackOverflow.

**Second:** by reading your logcat I understand that:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.shaktitool/com.example.shaktitool.Product}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: trying to requery an already closed cursor  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@41334490

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: trying to requery an already closed cursor  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@41334490
```

**So:** `trying to requery an already closed cursor` means that you do something wrong with SQLite. Post your java code and you'll get help.

Answer (score 0):

> trying to requery an already closed cursor  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@41334490

You are trying to access a Cursor that is already closed.

Don't close the cursor if you still need it or make a new DB query to get another one.

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: trying to requery an already closed
>   cursor.

Its hard to tell how you are queuing the cursor which you have already closed.
But one guess  is you may be using startManagingCursor() and passing it already closed cursor.